# How I can deform mesh without stretching?

Tags: modeling

I want bend paper edge without lousing its form and mass (without stretching it). Paper represented my plane:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). More complex folds can be done with a physics simulation, but it's often easier to just eyeball it using proportional editing and subdivision modifier. Also bending a real piece of paper as a reference works wonders :).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating an edge around another without stretching edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152922/rotating-an-edge-around-another-without-stretching-edges)   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130139/how-to-rotate-half-of-a-plane-around-the-split-edge-after-cutting-it-in-half-usi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the edge where you want to rotate the corner in edit mode, then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> --> cursor to selected (1). Set the transform pivot point to 3D cursor (2). Select the vertex you want to rotate and rotate it (3).

[image]

Comment: Great! Its works! Thank you  ^_^